# How do I get the images to show in divs, not only the link. Nuxt, CocktailDB API

Tags: image, api, axios, nuxt.js

Im building a simple app to practise Nuxt and axios with the CocktailDB API https://www.thecocktaildb.com/api.php. I have troubble getting the images to show rather than just the links. In console.log the links also shows. How do I get the images from the API to show in the list, and not only the link? Thanks in advance!

```
 <template>
      <div>
      <div>
        <SearchDrink/>
      </div>
      <div>
      <div v-for="drink in drinks" :key="drink.id"> 
      <div class="drink">
        <p> {{ drink.strDrink
        }} </p>
        <img src="" alt=""/> {{ drink.strDrinkThumb
        }}   
        <p>Instructions:</p>
        <p> {{ drink.strInstructions }} </p>
        <div class="ing"> Ingridients: 
        <p> {{ drink.strIngredient1 }} </p>
        <p> {{ drink.strIngredient2 }} </p>
        <p> {{ drink.strIngredient3 }} </p>
        <p> {{ drink.strIngredient4 }} </p>
        <p> {{ drink.strIngredient5 }} </p>
      </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </template>
    
    <script>
    import SearchDrink from '../../components/SearchDrink.vue'
    import axios from 'axios'
    
    export default {
      components:{
        SearchDrink,
      },
      data(){
        return {
          drinks: [],
        }
      },
     methods: {
        getAllDrinks(){
          axios.get('https://thecocktaildb.com/api/json/v1/1/search.php?s=')
          .then((response) => {
            this.drinks = response.data.drinks
            const myDrink = response.data.drinks
            console.log(myDrink)
            console.log(myDrink.strDrinkThumb)  
            })
        .catch((error) =>{
          console.log(error)
        })
        
        }, 
     },
      created(){
        this.getAllDrinks()
      },
      // methods: {
      //   searchDrink(){
      //     if(!this.search){
      //       return this.drinks
      //     }else{
      //       return this.drinks.filter(drink => 
      //       drink.text.toLowerCase().includes(this.search.
      //       toLowerCase()))
      //     }
      //   }
      // },
        head(){
            return {
                title: 'Drinks App',
                meta: [
                    {
                        hid: 'description',
                        name: 'description',
                        content: 'Best place to search a Drink'
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    }
    </script>
```

[image]

Comment: try `<img :src="drink.strDrinkThumb" alt=""/>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you're not putting the image inside the src tag.

This can be done using the `v-bind` directive as
`v-bind:src="..."` or `:src=".."`

### Example :

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  
  data: () => ({
    drinks: []
  }),
  mounted(){
    axios.get('https://thecocktaildb.com/api/json/v1/1/search.php?s=')
          .then((response) => {
            this.drinks = response.data.drinks
          })
  }
})
```

```css
img {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/axios/1.2.1/axios.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <ul>
    <li v-for="drink of drinks">
      <img :src="drink.strDrinkThumb"/>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```